# Custom Model API Validation in node.js

Tags: node.js, validation

I am creating backend apis for an application where i reauired to validate request payloads/parameters before processing and storing into my database. I am new to node.js eralier i used to validate same using using custom attributes in C# application. I want acheive same flexibility in node.js as well. What is the best approach i can go for?
Tons of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi). I use this library with [hapijs](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi), but you can use it alone or in combination with other frameworks. It's very flexible and configurable.